# Angular Sharing data between 2 components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that i am trying to share data between 2 components
I have put the service into module.ts providers
but have it in no other components providers array.
I have the service:ReferralDataService in the constructors of ReferralComponent and ReferMenuComponent

When I run the application I get this error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ReferralDataService

But if I put this service into each of the components i don't get an error.
But I don't get the shared data either

So HOW to solve this?

module.ts (relevant parts)

```
import { ReferMenuComponent } from './components/referMenu/referMenu.component';
import { ReferralComponent } from './components/referral/referral.component';
import { ReferralDataService } from './services/referralData.service';
@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, routing],
declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, LoginComponent,
                ReferMenuComponent, ReferralComponent],
providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },    
            AuthenticationService,ReferralDataService
           ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

The Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ReferralDataService {
    public referralData: any;
}
```

ReferralComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ReferralDataService } from '../../Services/referralData.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({

    templateUrl: 
'appThirdParty/app/Components/referral/referral.component.html',
    //providers: [ReferralDataService]
})
export class ReferralComponent implements OnInit {
    userFrm: FormGroup;
    referralData: {};
    routeOption: number;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private referralDataService: 
ReferralDataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userFrm = this.fb.group({
        });
        this.referralData = this.referralDataService.referralData;
        this.routeOption = this.route.snapshot.params['option'];
    }

}
```

ReferMenuComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ReferralDataService } from '../../Services/referralData.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { IPatient } from '../../Model/patient';
import { IHostData } from '../../Model/hostData';

import { DataRequestsToHost } from '../../Services/dataRequestsToHost.service';


@Component({

    templateUrl: 
'appThirdParty/app/Components/referMenu/referMenu.component.html',
    providers: [ DataRequestsToHost]
})
export class ReferMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    userFrm: FormGroup;
    option: number;
    dataFromHost: {};
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private referralDataService: 
ReferralDataService, private router: Router, private hostRequester: 
DataRequestsToHost) { }

     ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userFrm = this.fb.group({
         });
     }
    Option1Click() {
        this.option = 1
        this.getDataFromHost(this.option);
        this.sendDataToReferralService();
         this.router.navigate(["referral", { option: this.option }]);
    }
    Option2Click() {
         this.option = 2
         this.getDataFromHost(this.option);
        this.sendDataToReferralService();
        this.router.navigate(["referral", { option: this.option }]);
     }
     Option3Click() {
         this.option = 3
        this.getDataFromHost(this.option);
        this.sendDataToReferralService();
        this.router.navigate(["referral", { option: this.option }]);
    }
    getDataFromHost(option: number) {

        //var results = this.hostRequester.requestHostPatientData();
        this.dataFromHost  = this.requestThisPatientData();
    }
    sendDataToReferralService() {
        this.referralDataService.referralData = this.dataFromHost;
    }
    private requestThisPatientData(){
          console.log('GOT TO parent requestCurrentPatientData function');
         var currentUserTokenStr = localStorage.getItem('currentUserToken');
        var currentUserToken = JSON.parse(currentUserTokenStr);
        var currentProviderTokenStr = 
 localStorage.getItem('currentUserToken');
         var currentProviderToken = JSON.parse(currentProviderTokenStr);
        let patientData: IPatient = <IPatient>{};
        patientData.Id = 12345678;
    patientData.FirstName = 'Fred';
    patientData.LastName = 'Nurk';
    patientData.Gender = 'Male';
    patientData.StreetAddress = '3 Bowen Cresent';
    patientData.Suburb = 'Albert Park';
    patientData.State = 'Vic';
    patientData.Postcode = '3206';

    let returnObj: IHostData = <IHostData>{};
    returnObj.UserToken = currentUserToken;
    returnObj.ProviderToken = currentProviderToken;
    returnObj.Patient = patientData;
    return returnObj;
}
 }
```

Comment: You seem to have two different classes named the same way and located in two different places: `../../Services/referralData.service` (capital S), and `./services/referralData.service` (lowercase s).

Comment: ReferralComponent and ReferMenuComponent pages having its own modules file??

Answer (score -1):

In your module, you imported

```
import { ReferralDataService } from './services/referralData.service';
```

But in components you imported

```
import { ReferralDataService } from '../../Services/referralData.service';
```

The difference is between "Service" and "service"

Comment: that was the issue. gotta watch the case-senstivity